# Clustering signals with multiple parameters

Tags: clustering, signal-processing

I have a measurement that contains a couple of signals, let's say Power, Speed and Pressure. I would like to cluster these measurements.

At first I considered only one parameter at a time (for example, Power) and was able to cluster Power signals using K-medoids and DTW (Dynamic Time Warping).

Now I would like to cluster the whole measurements, that is, to consider all the parameters at once while clustering measurements. How to do that? Would it be enough to concatenate this signals? My reasoning is - three concatenated signals make a signal, so the procedure for clustering should be identical.

Is that so, or am I missing something? How to cluster measurements with multiple parameter signals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If DTW worked for you on a single variate, then use

Multivariate DTW

to analyze multiple variables at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But what do you mean by multivariate DTW,  the thing that I considered (concatenation of signals) or something else?

Comment: No, a "parallel" alignment. Like you do with trajectories. You don't concatenate x and y series there either.

Comment: Hmm...I haven't thought about it that way. Could you please provide some references, so I could better understand your idea? I have no experience in such an analysis, so I need to read a bit about it. I wouldn't bother you additionally, but I'm even missing good words to formulate a query that would give me adequate results :)

Comment: IIRC this was in the original DTW publication already. It treats the series as a number of points, and computes distances between them. Nothing about these being univariate.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that we're thinking about same thing. If I have two parameters, for example, power [2,5,3,4] and temperature [2, 2, 6], I would have a record like this [2, 5, 3, 4, 2, 2, 6] and consider it as a single signal (vector). That is what I mean by concatenation or appending. Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: For what I am suggesting, the series probably *need* to have the same measurement times. `[[x,y],[x,y],[x,y],[x,y]]`. Because you want to have the alignment consistent, too.

Comment: But isn't one of the main ideas about DTW to support signals of different length?It tries to find an alignment of signals by creating a distance matrix.That way it allows signals to have different length,to be shifted or skewed.I think that in your way I would make it impossible to align two records(of two parameters)if the form of the record is (x,y),(x,y),don't you think so?DTW tries to repeat some points, but would that be possible to do that this way?If you're record is x=[1,2], y=[3,4], you would have [1,3,2,4] instead of [1,2,3,4],so you cannot repeat some value if needed [1,1,1,2,3,4]?

Comment: As long as the length is in (x,y) pairs, two sequences *can* have a different length. [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]] vs. [[a1,b1],[a2,b2],[a3,b3]] by e.g. repeating the point [x2,y2]. Again, this is standard for trajectories.

Comment: Thanks, as I said, it wasn't clear to me when we started the discussion, but now it's getting clearer. Could you please, for the end, provide some useful links? Should I try finding material for something like "clustering trajectories", or something like that?

Comment: try `dtw trajectory`